# Unable to connect to RDS SQL Server with identical security

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-security-group

I've got 2 SQL Server databases hosted in Amazon's RDS system to power 2 copies of the same project.

They've got identical database names, identical passwords, identical security groups applied and are configured in build process.

Once built and hosted on elastic beanstalk both instances of the app work and can talk to their database.

However I can only connect to 1 of them with SQL Server Management Studio from my public IP.

Even if I open port 1433 to EVERYONE 0.0.0.0/0 I'm still unable to connect to the 2nd database.

Comment: It sounds like the "Publicly Accessible" flag is enabled on one of the RDS database instances, but not the other one.

Comment: @markb I didn't even know that was a parameter. But yes. That was it. No idea why I configured the other to allow it and one not!
Add an answer and I'll accept it!

Comment: Not really worth adding an answer since your question is a duplicate and should probably be closed. I answer this exact question at least once a week on here.